# AM572x - Access IPC between A15 and M4 using docker

Tags: docker, shared-libraries, ipc, rtos, texas-instruments

I am running my software in armv7 Ubuntu 16.04 docker container on A15 processor. My software is tested and works when I directly run it on A15 host. When the software is ran inside a docker container on A15 host, it uses libtiipc* libraries that are currently on host A15 processor. When I run the docker, software is unable to connect to ipu2 (M4 processor) and following error comes -

```
--> main:
Ipc_start: LAD_connect() failed: 4
Ipc_start failed: status = -1
<-- main:
```

I tired running the LAD daemon manually in the docker using `/usr/bin/lad_dra7xx -g -l lad.txt -p 777` and I get the following error in `/tmp/LAD/lad.txt` log file -

```
Initializing LAD... [0.653065] NameServer_setup: entered, refCount=0
[0.653130] NameServer_setup: creating listener thread
[0.653266] NameServer_setup: exiting, refCount=1
[0.653334] GateHWSpinlock_start: failed to open the spinlock device[0.653346]
ERROR: unable to start GateHWSpinlock
```

**Question -** 
What is the best way for the software inside docker to communicate with software on M4 using TI-RTOS IPC libraries? Please let me know if more information is required to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with enough tries -

1. Use `--privileged` in my docker run command and mount al TI libs and `/dev/mem` as volume instead of device.
2. Launch LAD daemon from inside the docker.
3. Launch the app that communicates with M4 using TI IPC inside the docker.